# Can Someone Help Me Fix This Wordpress Missing Argument Error?

Tags: mysql

I'm building a new website, and I'm using an old custom plugin I had made. The coder is nowhere to be found, email doesn't work so I'm hoping someone can help me here.

Using the latest version of Wordpress, I now get the error: (Missing argument 2 for wpdb::prepare()) This is part of the custom code, that I believe is causing the problem.

```
$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT
        ap.photo_id,
        ap.creation_date,
        ap.owner_id,
        ap.file_id,
        ap.title AS photo_title,
        ap.description,
        aa.album_id,
        aa.title AS album_title, 
        aa.category_id,
        sf.storage_path,
        u.displayname,
        u.username
    FROM 
        engine4_album_photos ap
        LEFT JOIN engine4_album_albums aa ON aa.album_id = ap.album_id AND category_id <> 0
        LEFT JOIN engine4_storage_files sf ON sf.".($thumbquality=='yes'?"parent_file_id":"file_id")." = ap.file_id AND sf.user_id = ap.owner_id
        JOIN engine4_authorization_allow auth ON auth.resource_id = aa.album_id AND auth.resource_type='album' AND auth.action='view' AND auth.role='everyone'
        JOIN engine4_users u ON u.user_id = ap.owner_id
    GROUP BY 
        ap.photo_id
    ORDER BY
        ap.creation_date DESC
    {$pullcount}");
```

If someone could help me out, I'd really appreciate it. I need to fix this so I don't get the errors and also so it's not open for some type of malicious injection. Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As it says in [wpdb::prepare](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/)

> Prepares a SQL query for safe execution. Uses sprintf()-like syntax.

Thus, if you change it to:

```
$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT
        ap.photo_id,
        ap.creation_date,
        ap.owner_id,
        ap.file_id,
        ap.title AS photo_title,
        ap.description,
        aa.album_id,
        aa.title AS album_title, 
        aa.category_id,
        sf.storage_path,
        u.displayname,
        u.username
    FROM 
        engine4_album_photos ap
        LEFT JOIN engine4_album_albums aa ON aa.album_id = ap.album_id AND category_id <> 0
        LEFT JOIN engine4_storage_files sf ON sf.%s = ap.file_id AND sf.user_id = ap.owner_id
        JOIN engine4_authorization_allow auth ON auth.resource_id = aa.album_id AND auth.resource_type='album' AND auth.action='view' AND auth.role='everyone'
        JOIN engine4_users u ON u.user_id = ap.owner_id
    GROUP BY 
        ap.photo_id
    ORDER BY
        ap.creation_date DESC %s", $thumbquality == 'yes' ? "parent_file_id" : "file_id", $pullcount);
```

you'll be fine.

**Edit:** I just edited the above code: in my original I forgot to remove the `{}` around the interpolated `$pullcount` when I replaced it with `%s`.

Comment: I have one more, still trying to figure out this website, see below:

Comment: Actually, I take it back, I was editing wrong website, LOL. I now get no results displayed, but no errors either.

Comment: @rolandogomez see the edit I just made.  that should get you results with no PHP errors .

Comment: I made the edits, it pulls up the data, but I get this error code: Warning: Missing argument 2 for wpdb::prepare(), called in /home/domain/public_html/wp-content/plugins/I4US_SE_Latest_Members/index.php on line 82 and defined in /home/domain/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1291